# ASP Cookie on php Pages

Tags: php, asp.net

I have my login script in asp which sets the cookies using **response.cookie**.

Now when i try to read the cookie value using `$_COOKIE` in php.

It was all working fine in php 5.6, but when i upgraded to php 7.4.6 the returned value adds a "+" sign in between the words instead of space.

Please suggest a solution at the `php.ini` level as adding urldecode function in all my php scripts is not possible.

Comment: Can you post a redacted sample of a cookie? Also, is there anything between the ASP and PHP sides that might be messing with things?

Comment: i dont think so....can you elaborate more on the cookie information you want? and of which side?